# True or false? The mapping $\left \langle v,w \right \rangle=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}}$ defines a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given is the vector space $(\mathbb{R}^n,+, \cdot)$ over the field
>   $(\mathbb{R},+, \cdot)$. For arbitrary elements $v$ and $w \in
> \mathbb{R}^n$, the following mapping $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot
> \right \rangle$ is defined: $$\left \langle v,w \right
> \rangle=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}}$$
>
> Does it define a scalar product?

I think there are usually 4 conditions to be shown that can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

But for this example I think I don't need to go through each condition because if we take a negative element $v,w$, we get no solution after taking its square root? Thus the statement is false.

On the other hand this might not be necessarily true because I thought we could also form this a bit:

$$\left \langle v,w \right
\rangle=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}} \Leftrightarrow \left \langle v,w \right
\rangle^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}$$

and then we wouldn't have problems with negative elements inside square root?

This is alson very confusing because we have sums here : /

How could this be solved correctly?

Comment: it isn't even well-defined on $\mathbb R^n$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume false just because $\forall a \not \in \{0,1\}$ we have $$a \langle v, w\rangle = a \sqrt{\sum v_i} \sqrt{\sum w_i} = \sqrt{\sum a^2 v_i} \sqrt{\sum w_i} \neq \sqrt{\sum a v_i} \sqrt{\sum w_i} = \langle av, w \rangle$$

Your point about negative one is a particular example of the above, and is sufficient to show this isn't an inner product.

Comment: This is a good argument since it would still apply if one replaced $v_i\to |v_i|$. (By contrast, this does remove the negative case.)